# How to use a while loop in Expect script for a certain prompt to appear?

Tags: bash, shell, expect

I am using Expect language to automate a shell program that does the following:

There is a long AGREEMENT TEXT and the user should press SPACE for a few times until a prompt appears, which asks:

```
"Please type ACCEPT or EXIT:"
```

So if I want to emulate the user interaction in the Expect script it's like:

```
send -- " "
send -- " "
send -- " "
send -- " "
send -- " "
send -- " "
expect "*Please type ACCEPT or EXIT:*"
send -- "EXIT\r"
```

So what I want obviously is a way for the program to enter space until the prompt of "Please type..." appears on the screen, naturally, it seems like a while loop, what I want to do is: (pseudo-code):

```
while (expect "Please type ACCEPT or EXIT:" == -1) { //it doesn't appear
    send -- " "
}
```

What is the correct syntax for this situation?

Comment: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/while.htm for starters. Time to learn tcl.

Comment: Already bumped into it, still, this specific scenario I mentioned in the question is something I am not familiar with, "expect ..." returns a boolean or something?

Comment: Is there a "press space to continue" prompt?

Comment: No, there is only a message, in the beginning, saying: "press space to move through the AGREEMENT" and at the end of it, there is the "PLEASE type" prompt, sometimes it takes 6 or 7 spaces to get there, I know where to start but I can't say when it will finish.

Comment: Expect uses the [Tcl language](http://www.tcl.tk/). If you are more comfortable with shell syntax you can try my [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect).